# select selected option by value with jquery

Tags: jquery, select, selectedvalue

in order  to set the selected option by value for a html select with jquery 
i do this as follows:

```
 $('#mySelectId option[value="avancement d\'échelon"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

is the problem because my string value contains `'` ?

Comment: Code works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/HN3Ba/

Comment: Is it really the value, or are you actually trying to target the text in the option?

Comment: i forgot to say that the problem appears just with this string ; when i set the value to for example 'rétrogradation' , there is no problem

Comment: @ Rory McCrossan i tried your example it works fine with me , but with my select it doesn't work , given that the option values are listed from a database , can this be the source of the problem ?

Comment: to be more precise what i want to do is as follows : `$("#sanction option[value='<%=General.charcterEscape(plainte.getSanction())%>']").attr("selected","selected");`  charcterEscape is a method wich replace "'" with "\'" in a string and the plainte.getSanction()='avancement d'échelon' in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
$('#mySelectId option[value="avancement d\'échelon"]').attr("selected", true);
```

instead.

Also to remove the selected attribute use

```
$('#mySelectId option[value="avancement d\'échelon"]').attr("selected", false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also just set the `.val()` of the select box.

```
$('#mySelectId').val("avancement d'échelon");
```

Comment: i forgot to say that the problem appears just with this string ; when i set the value to for example 'rétrogradation' , there is no problem